# get the average of some ranges of dates in pandas

Tags: python, average, date-range, pandas

I need to group the data by customer_id and get the average of purchase dates intervals. My data looks like this:

```
date        customer_id
1/1/2020        1
1/2/2020        2
1/3/2020        3
1/4/2020        1
1/5/2020        2
1/1/2021        1
1/2/2021        2
1/3/2021        3
```

So I need to see what is the average date ranges for each customer. The desired output is:

```
customer_id        Average_date_ranges(in months)
    1                       7
    2                       5
    3                       12
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you haven't already, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). What have you tried, and what errors are you receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approximation using `groupby_apply` could be:

```
>>> df.groupby('customer_id', as_index=False)['date'] \
      .apply(lambda x: round(x.diff().mean().days / 30, 0))

   customer_id  date
0            1   6.0
1            2   6.0
2            3  12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use transforming the *date* column type into a `datetime` object then call `groupby` to get the average date. You can use code below:

```py
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df.groupby("customer_id").mean()
```